# How to calculate simple moving average

Tags: ruby, math, moving-average

I am working on a program that uses yahoo finance api to collect the historical close data for the number of stocks entered and then go ahead and calculate simple moving average (SMA) for the data for period of 30 days. I have the following so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yahoofinance'

array = []
while line = gets
  break if line.chomp =~ /N/ #exit when 'N' is entered
  array << line.chomp
end
puts "Values: #{array.join(',')}" #joining all the elements with a comma

array.each do |s|
  print "\n______\n"
  puts s

  YahooFinance::get_HistoricalQuotes( s,
                                  Date.parse( '2012-10-06' ),
                                  Date.today() ) do |hq|
    puts "#{hq.close}"
  end
end
```

This code is giving me the close values for stocks for the specified range. I have two questions:

1. Currently, `hq.close` is holding values for all stocks. How can I put these values in an array so that I can do a computation on it to calculate a SMA for each stock data?

   I tried doing something like this:

   ```
   "#{hq.close}" my_val = [hq.close]
   puts my_val
   ```

   But this only gives the value of first stock in `my_val`. I know I have to put a loop here. I tried putting

   ```
   while(!hq.close.emply?)
     my_val = [hq.close]
     puts my_val
   end
   ```

   But this gives me an error:

   ```
   C:/Users/Muktak/workspace/RubySample/sample_program.rb:23:in block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined methodemplty?' for 19.52:Float (NoMethodError) from
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yahoofinance-1.2.2/lib/yahoofinance.rb:491:in block in get_HistoricalQuotes' from
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yahoofinance-1.2.2/lib/yahoofinance.rb:456:inblock in get_historical_quotes' from
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yahoofinance-1.2.2/lib/yahoofinance.rb:456:in each' from
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yahoofinance-1.2.2/lib/yahoofinance.rb:456:inget_historical_quotes' from
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yahoofinance-1.2.2/lib/yahoofinance.rb:489:in get_HistoricalQuotes' from
   C:/Users/Muktak/workspace/RubySample/sample_program.rb:19:inblock in ' from
   C:/Users/Muktak/workspace/RubySample/sample_program.rb:13:in each' from
   C:/Users/Muktak/workspace/RubySample/sample_program.rb:13:in'
   Values: FB,GOOG
   ```
2. How can I calculate a SMA in Ruby?

Comment: There is no `emply?` method, `empty?` on the other hand...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing out the typo error. But even after correction, I am still getting the same error. I am thinking of one other approach. Since hq.close contains list of stock symbols with their closing values, can I do two loops on this object, first for iterating over the object to get the number of lists and second to get the respective values in the list. I know this is very much possible in Java. Is there any way to do this in ruby? Please provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked two questions here, so let's address them one at a time.

First, this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yahoofinance'

stock_names = %w{MSFT RHT AAPL}
start = Date.parse '2012-10-06'
finish = Date.today
closes = {}

stock_names.each do |stock_name|
  quotes = YahooFinance::get_HistoricalQuotes stock_name, start, finish
  closes[stock_name] = quotes.collect { |quote| quote.close }
end
```

... will produce the following hash in `closes`, which I understand is in the format you want:

```
{
  "AAPL" => [629.71, 628.1, 640.91, 635.85, 638.17],
  "RHT"=> [53.69, 53.77, 53.86, 54.0, 54.41],
  "MSFT"=> [29.2, 28.95, 28.98, 29.28, 29.78]
}
```

Secondly, you want to calculate a simple moving average - which for financial applications is just [the mean of the values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average).  There is a Gem called simple_statistics that can do this.

This code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yahoofinance'
require 'simple_statistics'

stock_names = %w{MSFT RHT AAPL}
start = Date.parse '2012-10-06'
finish = Date.today
averages = {}

stock_names.each do |stock_name|
  quotes = YahooFinance::get_HistoricalQuotes stock_name, start, finish
  closes = quotes.collect { |quote| quote.close }
  averages[stock_name] = closes.mean
end
```

... produces the following hash in `averages`:

```
{ "AAPL" => 634.548, "MSFT" => 29.238, "RHT" => 53.946 }
```