# Calculate moving averages with ruby and simple_statistics and appending to JSON

Tags: ruby, yahoo-finance

I am trying to calculate moving averages (simple and exponential) and I have come across the simple_statistics gem, which is perfect for my needs.  I am trying to modify the code from this link: [How to calculate simple moving average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883917/how-to-calculate-simple-moving-average)) for my purposes.

GOAL:
I have a JSON like this which lists historical prices for a single stock over a long time period:

```
[
  {
    "Low": 8.63,
    "Volume": 14211900,
    "Date": "2012-10-26",
    "High": 8.79,
    "Close": 8.65,
    "Adj Close": 8.65,
    "Open": 8.7
  },
```

To this, I would like to add moving averages for each day (simple and exponential - which the simple_statistics gem seems to do easily) for 20, and 50 day averages (and others as required) so it would appear something like this for each day:

```
[
  {
    "Low": 8.63,
    "Volume": 14211900,
    "Date": "2012-10-26",
    "High": 8.79,
    "Close": 8.65,
    "Adj Close": 8.65,
    "Open": 8.7,
    "SMA20":
    "SMA50":
  },
```

I would prefer to use the yahoo_finance, and simple_statistics gems and then append the output to the original JSON as I have a feeling that once I gain a better understanding, it will be easier for me to modify.

Right now, I'm still reading up on how I will do this (any help is appreciated)  Below is my attempt to calculate a 20 day simple moving average for Microsoft (doesn't work).  This way (using HistoricalQuotes_days) seems to assume that the start date is today, which wont work for my overall goal.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yahoofinance'
require 'simple_statistics'

averages = {}

dates.each do |dates|
  quotes = YahooFinance::get_HistoricalQuotes_days ( 'MSFT' , 20 ) start, finish
  closes = quotes.collect { |quote| quote.close }
  averages = closes.mean
end
```

Thank you

UPDATE: I don't actually need to use YahooFinance gem as I already have the data in a JSON.  What I dont know how to do is pull from the JSON array, make the calculations using the simple_statistics gem, and then add the new data into the original JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the gem, I see two ways to get your data. Here they are (note they both can take a block):

```
YahooFinance::get_HistoricalQuotes_days('MSFT', 20)
```

Which returns an array of YahooFinance::HistoricalQuote objects with the following methods:

```
[ :recno, :recno=, :symbol, :symbol=, :date, :date=, 
  :open, :open=, :high, :high=, :low, :low=, :close, 
  :close=, :adjClose, :adjClose=, :volume, :volume=, 
  :to_a, :date_to_Date  ]
```

Or:

```
YahooFinance::get_historical_quotes_days('MSFT', 20)
```

which returns an array of values [from the documentation](http://www.transparentech.com/projects/yahoofinance) :

```
Getting the historical quote data as a raw array.
The elements of the array are:
  [0] - Date
  [1] - Open
  [2] - High
  [3] - Low
  [4] - Close
  [5] - Volume
  [6] - Adjusted Close
```

And to take an average (simple moving average), you can easily do:

`ary.reduce(:+) / ary.length`

Where `ary` would hold the values to average (need to be floats or it will integer divide). To do the exponential moving average, just use the following formula:

```
(close - previous_ema) * (2 / (amount_of_days_ago + 1) ) + previous_ema
```

Where close is the stock's close, previous_ema is yesterday's ema, and amount_of_days_ago is the range of the average into the past, for instance 20 (days).

### edit

oh. Yeah parsing json is easy: https://github.com/flori/json

I can't write a whole beginning ruby guide, but the basics for what you need are `Hash` and `Array`. Look up how to use ruby hashes and arrays, and thats probably a good 30% of ruby programming right there.

For example to get the json objects in an array and then get just the closes, you could use Array#map like so:

```
stocks = JSON.parse( your_json_here )
array = stocks.map{ |hash| hash["Close"] }
# => [8.65, 9.32, etc... ]
```

hope that gets you started n good luck

Comment: Actually, I believe Array#mean etc.. are core extensions that (for good or bad) one of those gems uses to make things simpler.

Comment: well yea you can open up the `Array` class just as easily and make a method `mean`

Comment: Hmm, yes I guess I'm saying that the gems in question already did that.

Comment: AJ, thanks for your help. I know for many parsing JSON is easy. I do have the calculations for stdev (not using yours, I'm doing an n-1 stdev). I have done this calc on paper (and more often Excel), but don't know how to turn it into Ruby (which is why I'm using simple_stats).  I know that to parse JSON I can do JSON.parse json but how to do the calculations for each day in the array and then return the results to create a new JSON still eludes me (I need more of a dummys guide - if you can point me to any tutorials online it would be great).  Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: edited response. Do some tutorials is my advice. When in doubt print out `object_variable.class` on an object to see what you're working with and google it to get some documentation on how to use it